# Quarantine alert for Skim

Tags: macos, launch-services

I'm on Mountain Lion. Every time I double-click on a pdfd (pdf bundle) document, I get the alert saying that I'm opening Skim for the first time (which is, of course, false).

I've completely disabled the quarantine system. I also tried to reset the LaunchServices database.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you running Skim from its mounted dmg?

Comment: No: it's in the Applications folder

Comment: [Another question like this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62708/why-do-i-have-repeated-are-you-sure-you-want-to-open-it-messages-when-launchi) was solved with `sudo xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/$app.app`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved: I had to trash Skim, rebuild the LaunchServices database, restore Skim and rebuild the database once again.